# Сжатие Javascript и CSS

Tags: java

Прочитал небольшую статью на тему сжатия файлов и не смог добиться выполнения команд через командную строку. Вот здесь можно ознакомиться: http://javascript.ru/optimize/javascript-compression#comment-14650. Перепробовал много различных вариантов и никак. Кто-нибудь пользуется этими методами? Подскажите, пошагово, что нужно сделать, чтобы воспользоваться компрессором **YUI Compressor**.

У меня в итоге в командной строке пишет, что java не является внутренней или внешней командой.

В переменные среды прописал:

Path=**C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin**;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;

В общем, что и где должно лежать, и что и где должно быть прописано, чтобы компрессор работал?

Comment: Работает без проблем. Java 1.6.0.29

Comment: Установил Java 1.6.0.29 и всё получилось. Спасибо.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если cmd выдает что "java не является внутренней или внешней командой." то это значит только то, что путь к java.exe не входит в PATH. по дефолку jdk ставится в `c:\program files\java\jdk.` 
поэтому скорее всего вам надо в PATH прописать `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` или `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin`

Answer (score 0):

У вас действительно JDK установлен в `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0`?

Comment: При установке jdk-7u2-windows-x64.exe я указываю установщику, чтобы установка производилась в папку Java. Затем установщик устанавливается jre7, я также указываю папку Java. Затем установщик устанавливает JavaFX 2.0 Runtime и JavaFX 2.0 SDK. Я оставляю по умолчанию (Programm Files\Oracle). Папку с yuicompressor-2.4.7 тоже кидаю в папку Java.

Перезагрузка. В переменных средах создаю (на данный момент):

Имя переменной: Path.
Значение переменной: C:\Java\jre7\bin;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem.

Что я неправильно делаю из вышеперечисленного? )) Опишите Ваш путь.)

Comment: Добавлю.
В командной строке потом захожу в папку yuicompressor-2.4.7\build
---
Там лежит файл yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar. В эту же папку кидаю файл для сжатия. В командной строке набираю команду:
java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar myfile.js -o myfile-min.js
---
И получаю:
"java" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
---
P.S. Только начал эту тему изучать. Так что извиняюсь за, скорее всего, банальный вопрос. ))

Answer (score 0):

Я вот этим пользуюсь: [javascriptcompressor.com](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Для работы YUI compressor нужен не JDK, а JRE, соответственно в PATH нужно прописать путь к JRE, т.е. к той папке, к которой будет лежать java.exe

А вообще я советую использовать Google Closure Compiler с опцией simple optimizations. На том же javascript.ru есть целый цикл статей о GCC

Comment: Спасибо. Тоже попробую, но хотелось бы и с тем, что выше тоже разобраться.